# Is middleware considered server or client-side in Next.js 13?

Tags: next.js, middleware

I'm currently working on a Next.js 13 project and I'm trying to understand the role of middleware within the framework. In Next.js 13, is middleware considered server-side or client-side?

I have looked at the Next.js documentation where i can't find an explanation whether middleware is client side or server side.

Could someone clarify whether middleware in Next.js 13 is categorized as server-side or client-side? Additionally, it would be helpful to understand any specific use cases or limitations for middleware in this version of Next.js.

Comment: It's server side of course (just because to do anything with the response you need to import `import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'`). As for use cases, it's too broad question, it basically allows you to do anything with the response. From the docs: `you can modify the response by rewriting, redirecting, modifying the request or response headers, or responding directly.`

Comment: There are a number of places in Next where the conventions of "servers" get blenderized with the conventions of "clients", because the whole brand of Next is SSR and combining those two. This does not, however, mean that everywhere you see a traditionally "server-side" syntax convention is inherently a server-only functionality. In this case, it would be more precise to say that 'request' and 'response' are conventions for the general concept of route-handlers, and client-side applications certainly have those, and a 'router'.

Answer (score 1):

It can be used on the client side.

I personally prefer to use route authentication, because it checks the token before the page rerenders.

**Note:** If you use the `React`'s context and try to access a protected route, you first load the page and then the context is set, so you go outside the application (you can make it work better but basically it's the behavior).

The downside is that you have to be aware that there is a middleware in your application and you need to set it to pages/routes that you want to access.

For more information, I found [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-next-js-middleware-edge-functions/#:%7E:text=js%20middleware%3F-,Middleware%20in%20Next.,over%20the%20request%2Fresponse%20flow) that I found clarifying.